# Fatal error: Call to undefined function entity_view_mode_prepare() /sites/all/modules/field_collection/field_collection.entity.inc on line 600

Tags: entities

I get this error as I was doing my work. How do I fix this fatal error?

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function entity_view_mode_prepare() in
>   .sites/all/modules/field_collection/field_collection.entity.inc on
>   line 600

Comment: Make sure you're using a recent release of Drupal (that function was added in 7.33) and make sure field collection is up to date. If that doesn't fix it, we'll need some more details

Comment: What happened did you do before this happened?

Answer (score 1):

This error has been removed in latest drupal 7 versions. Please upgrade your drupal core version to the latest.

OR
Temporary solution:
Copy and paste the below function in includes/common.inc file

```
function entity_view_mode_prepare($entity_type, $entities, $view_mode, $langcode = NULL) {
if (!isset($langcode)) {
$langcode = $GLOBALS['language_content']->language;
}

// To ensure hooks are never run after field_attach_prepare_view() only
// process items without the entity_view_prepared flag.
$entities_by_view_mode = array();
foreach ($entities as $id => $entity) {
$entity_view_mode = $view_mode;
if (empty($entity->entity_view_prepared)) {

  // Allow modules to change the view mode.
  $context = array(
    'entity_type' => $entity_type,
    'entity' => $entity,
    'langcode' => $langcode,
  );
drupal_alter('entity_view_mode', $entity_view_mode, $context);
}

$entities_by_view_mode[$entity_view_mode][$id] = $entity;
}

return $entities_by_view_mode;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Neeraj, thank you for the tip. It is highly discouraged to alter core files however, maybe you can provide instructions on how to deal with this error in another way?

Comment: Please upgrade Drupal version to the latest then if you want get rid off this error. All cores files will be upgraded.
This was just quick fix.

Comment: You can do this like below:

1. Create a directory on the site root(Next to includes) named as custom_include(in my case)
2. Create a file "custom_includes.inc" in that folder.
3. Now copy/define your function in this file
4. Load this file with the help of your custom existing module in hook_init function. 
    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/custom_includes/custom_common.inc'; 
5. This file will be loaded in all over the project.